# Use the JWT generated by Azure AD to access custom API server

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am authenticating to my React app using Azure Entra ID Auth.

The JWT issued by Azure AD is valid for about 75 minutes.

I am saving this JWT in localstorage, and using it for connecting it with my custom API server.

My custom API decodes the email from the JWT. My Custom API doesnt care if the token is expires.

Is this approach secure?